# Create/manage two displays in the same window in Pygames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pygame, window

I am just starting to look into Pygames, and am pretty armature when it comes to programming GUIs in general, but what I'm trying to create a simulation that is controlled by a user interface on the left side of the window. That is, both the simulation and the interface are on the same window as seen here:

[image]

I've been looking over a lot of similar questions/examples online, but they all are very in-depth and I really need something very dumbed down. That is to say, all I want to know is how to create the two displays on one window as shown above. I extracted some code for the "Simulation" part of it, which is generally outlined something like this:

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.font.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 20)

pygame.init()
width = 1000
height = 600
main_s = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            None

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

As for the "Interface" component, I was planning on putting in a form using Tkinter, and using the input from that to manipulate the "Simulation".

I have seen some examples mention something about multiple scenes and classes. I don't know if that's what I'm looking for or not (since for whatever reason they never showed output), but as the code I copied above never mentions classes or scenes, I have no idea how that would be incorporated.

So before I run off and make things more complicated than necessary, I figured it was easier to simply ask: what is a simple outline to implement the configuration/interface I need?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the easiest thing would be to just create two separate surfaces and treat them as separate screens. For example, if you have a 800 x 600 window, you could create a 600 x 600 image and a 200 x 600 image.

Something like this...

```
...

actual_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
simulation_screen = pygame.Surface((600, 600))
interface_screen = pygame.Surface((200, 600))

...

while running:

  # ... game code that renders to each surface as though
  # they are separate screens ...

  actual_screen.blit(simulation_screen, (0, 0))
  actual_screen.blit(interface_screen, (600, 0))
  pygame.display.flip()

  ...
```